# How to fix HTTP error when uploading larger (> 10MBish) .wav files to my wordpress installation?

Tags: wordpress

I have tried the usual PHP settings which are all set to 127MB. Smaller files upload fine. I have spent hours googling and have not found any working solutions.

Comment: In media page in upload file field, what is the max file size written there?

Comment: What HTTP error do you get?

Comment: It was 403 - permission denied. Max file size says 127 MB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, my PHP configuration in php.ini was correct which was why the correct upload limit was showing up in the media page. The PHP settings were not being applied to every subdirectory however. To fix this I had to add the following line to my .htaccess file.

SuPHP_ConfigPath /path_to_my_php_ini_file_goes_here/php.ini